# How to add a css file to an open window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, w3c

I am trying to open a new html window and link it to an external css file..

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow");

var fileref=document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", 'kamusi_ext-v1.css');

myWindow.document.head.appendChild(fileref);
```

However I am getting this error:

> script.js:70 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

When running the same script on Firefox, I am not getting this error but the css is not being applied!

Comment: suggest use postMessage, it's a security issue, your way sure wont cross broswer, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage, u can post your style uri and append in receive

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work here :|[image]

[image]

I think it is related to cross-origin thing. Googling the error you provided would give you a hint. Good luck!